# not able to save UIImage from iphone photolibrary

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to save a image by picking it from iphone photo library. But I am not able to save it. My UIImage object suddenly releases. I am getting following error:
*** -[UIImage release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x83fa5b0

Please check my code below:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSLog(@"finish picking media");

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){

        UIImage *selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSLog(@"found an image");

        selectedImage=[self scaleAndRotateImage:selectedImage];
        NSLog(@"image scaled");
        //add image to mainpic
        imgvwProfile.image = selectedImage;
        NSLog(@"11");
        //[ setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.imgPic=selectedImage;
        //self.isMainPicImageModified=YES;
        NSLog(@"22");
        //[self sendImage:selectedImage];
        NSLog(@"selectedimage width:%f ht:%f",selectedImage.size.width,selectedImage.size.height);
        [self saveImage:selectedImage withImageName:@"profilePic.png"];
        NSLog(@"33");
    }
}
```

The error appears when NSLog(@"11"); has been execute.
Can some one please help me why I am getting this error?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change below line and check whether this statement makes problem or not.

```
 imgvwProfile.image = selectedImage;
                To
 imgvwProfile.image = [selectedImage retain];
```

Let me know now your app crash in this function or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the error occurs immediatly after NSLog(@"11") has been executed (you see 11 in the console right?), then it's happening while releasing the former UIImage of self.imgPic. To verify this just put `self.imgPic = null;` at the beginning of the method.

If so check your code for former release calls on imgPic or other variables pointing to the same UIImage instance. Maybe in `scaleAndRotateImage` or other methods.